# Is there anything similar to Kirby or Jekyll for .NET?

Tags: .net, content-management-system, jekyll

I'm looking into CMS solutions for my company (Because I'm sick of coding press releases and other things that people should be able to do themselves). I've run into [Kirby](http://getkirby.com) and [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) that generate database-free sites that can be edited through standard markdown. This is very appealing to me and I think it could be a great solution for our team but the problem is we run on .NET and it's very unlikely that we will change anytime soon as it would require some serious restructuring and our resource are currently tied up with other things.

I was just wondering if there are any comprable solutions out there for .NET?

Comment: Why don't you just set up a Linux VM with an Apache web server?

Answer (score 4):

Keep an eye on [Pretzel](https://github.com/Code52/pretzel):

> A simple, pluggable site generation tool for .NET developers and Windows users

https://github.com/Code52/pretzel

Comment: Sadly, their wiki page is pretty bare bones: https://github.com/Code52/pretzel/wiki